# vb.net dictionary of string,dictionary...after filling readout always empty

Tags: vb.net

I need to do some comparing and shuffling of fields, (i come from a more PHP background and working with arrays is completely different, as suggested after readin many things here I know VB.NET uses LIST and Dictionary easier.

I have a dictionary (of string, dictionary (of string,string)) which is filled well, but after I try to read it out, it's always empty....

below I fill a few things. The var I am talking about it
fillDictionary inside the matcheswholename VALUES part.
I fill up the fillDictionary and add it to the matchesWholename
Afterwhich I clear it, because it is in a loop and more is to come.

```
Dim matchesTotal As New List(Of String)
        Dim fillDictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
        Dim matchesWholename As New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String))

        Try
            If ds.Tables("matchesWholename").Rows.Count > 0 Then
                For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables("matchesWholename").Rows

                    If Not matchesWholename.ContainsKey(CStr(dr("key"))) Then
                         fillDictionary.Add("programme", CStr(dr("programme")))
                        fillDictionary.Add("remark", CStr(dr("remark")))
                        fillDictionary.Add("key", CStr(dr("key")))
                        fillDictionary.Add("displayname", CStr(dr("prop_value")))
                        Console.WriteLine("count before insert {0}", fillDictionary.Count)
                        matchesWholename.Add(CStr(dr("sanction_key")), fillDictionary)
                    End If
                    If Not matchesTotal.Contains(CStr(dr("key"))) Then
                        matchesTotal.Add(CStr(dr("key")))
                    End If
                    fillDictionary.Clear()
                Next
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("Err: {0}", ex.Message)
        End Try
```

When later I try to readout like this, it returns nothing....
I am actually sending a copy of the filldictionary into it or not? or does my clear() method clear what's inside it?

```
Dim pair As KeyValuePair(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String))
        Dim subpair As KeyValuePair(Of String, String)
        For Each pair In matchesWholename
            ' Display Key and Value.
            For Each subpair In pair.Value
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", pair.Key, subpair.Key, subpair.Value)
            Next

        Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fillDictionary.Clear()` looks somewhat suspicious.  You're essentially clearing the dictionary each iteration of your `For` loop.

Comment: yes because after putting it in that matchesWholename dictionary, I will reuse it, but don' want the old results.

Comment: @renevdkooi, have you debugged through this to see if anything is ever added to the `matchesWholename` dictionary?

Comment: actually you might be right, I see that when I don't do it it does get filled, but not correct... I thought adding would bake a copy of it, not put the actual reference of it

Comment: @renevdkooi, yes you're adding a reference to the same `fillDictionary` each time, it's not creating a copy.

Comment: @renevdkooi, `matchesWholename.Add(CStr(dr("sanction_key")), New Dictionary(Of String, String)(fillDictionary))`

Comment: perfect! thanks....actually when I was waiting for your answer, i solved it by creating a sub which takes byref of matcheswholename and the byval of the filldictionary... just a way around...your's is better...thanks again