# Looping through Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String))

Tags: vb.net

Similar question here, but no answer : [vb.net dictionary of string,dictionary...after filling readout always empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664250/vb-net-dictionary-of-string-dictionary-after-filling-readout-always-empty)

I fill as List(Of String) with rows of text from a file and then add it to a Dictionary. The method I use to fill this Dictionary works as it should. I create:

```
Private dictDictionary As Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String))
```

loop through the text file and adding each row to a list then add that list to the dictionary with the file name as key like so:

```
dictDictionary.Add(sFileName, sFileRows)
```

sFileRows is a List(Of String) containing a MAX of 1056 elements that I need to move around based on specific options. The problem I'm having is accessing this List(Of Strings) by the Key.

I've tried:

```
    For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, List(Of String)) In dictDictionary

        Dim sKey As String = kvp.Key
        Dim tempRows As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
        tempRows = dictDictionary.item(sKey)

        Next
```

No matter what I try when I assign the List(Of String) in the Dictionary to a new List it is always empty. But the original dictionary has the rows in the List(Of String) that I read from the text file.

First Method that fills the dictionary:

```
Private Sub GetInfo()
    Try
        Dim sFileName As String = String.Empty
        Dim sFileRows As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
        If IO.Directory.Exists("some directory")Then
            Dim Files() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles("directory and file type")
            For Each File As String In Files
                sFileName = Path.GetFileName(File)
                Dim rdrRows As StreamReader = New StreamReader(File)
                Dim sString As String
                While rdrRows.Peek() >= 0
                    sString = rdrRows.ReadLine()
                    sFileRows.Add(sString)
                End While
                'Actually adding the info to the dictionary
                dictDictionary.Add(sFileName, sFileRows)
                rdrRows.Dispose()
                sFileRows.Clear()
            Next
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

Second Method to manipulate the order of elements in the List(Of String)

```
Private Sub ChangeStructure()     
For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, List(Of String)) In dictDictionary
        Dim rows As List(Of String) = kvp.Value
        For Each item As String In rows
            MessageBox.Show(item.ToString)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

There is nothing in the List(Of String) now but there was when it was filled in GetInfo()

Comment: Please show a short but complete program (just a short console app) demonstrating the problem, instead of just snippets. (And the other question you've linked to *does* have an answer...)

Answer (score 3):

Should be as easy as

```
Dim data = New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String)) From _
{
    {"Foo", New List(Of String) From {"1", "2", "3"}},
    {"Bar", New List(Of String) From {"4", "5", "6"}}
}

For Each kvp in data
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key & " says:")
    For Each str in kvp.Value
        Console.WriteLine(str)
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, List(Of String)) In dictDictionary

    Dim rows As List(Of String) = kvp.Value
    If rows Is Nothing Then Continue
    For Each item As String in rows

        '...

    Next item

Next kvp
```

Answer (score 0):

You're are using `kvp.Key`, why are you not using `kvp.Value`?

```
    For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, List(Of String)) In dictDictionary
        Dim sKey As String = kvp.Key
        Debug.Print("Filename: " & sKey)
        Dim tempRows As List(Of String) = kvp.Value
        Debug.Print("# of Lines: " & tempRows.Count)
        Debug.Print("------------------------------")
        For Each line As String In tempRows
            Debug.Print(line)
        Next
        Debug.Print("------------------------------")
        Debug.Print("")
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
sFileRows.Clear()
```

List(Of String) is a reference type.  After you fill the list and add it to the dictionary, you clear it, so it is empty when you try to access it later.

The solution is to create a new list each time in the loop.  In other words, move this line:

```
Dim sFileRows As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
```

inside the For loop and get rid of the call to `.Clear()`